# Is it possible to query SAS tables from SSMS?

Tags: odbc, ssms, oledb, enterprise-guide

I want to know if it's possible to query SAS EG data from the SSMS interface in a new query and store the results (if any) in a temp table.

I've seen a lot of material for connecting SAS EG to SSMS. But not a lot for connecting SSMS to SAS EG. I primarily use SSMS and want to pass SAS code or whatever from SSMS and retrieve data.

```
BEGIN 
Select * into #GetSasData from (

SomeFunctionorProceedureinSSMSthatPullsSASData("Proc SQL Create table A as Select ... ; end;)
) [A]

Select * from #GetSasData
END
```

Comment: Give me any solution. I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Does you SAS installation (not EG as EG is just gui front end) have SAS/Share?  If so you should be able to install SAS ODBC drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm part of a large organization and there are many users on SAS and SSMS. My SaS EG can retrieve data from SSMS via the ODBC option in SAS, it's slow, but it works. So given this, can I do the same from SSMS?